# Insert new row in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

The current code adds a row to the DB. If I reuse this code, it will update the existing row instead of creating a new one. How to create a new row using the same code?

---

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateFactory.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Item item = new Item();
item.setName("name");
item.setPrice(122.3);
item.setCount(225);
session.persist(item);

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
}
```

Item extended AbstractEntity

Comment: Spring Data JPA can help you do this easily and many more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate uses `persistence.xml` or `hibernate.cfg.xml` to read the database properties.
To insert a new row the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` has to be set to `update` instead of `create-drop` or `create`

```xml
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
</properties>
```

Below you will find a link with the description for every value:
[What are the possible values of the Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto configuration and what do they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha)